# Desired Verson of JDK in conda environment

Tags: java, windows, conda, virtualenv

My Conda Environment is reading a wrong version of JDK.

I have JDK 11 and JDK 17 Installed on Windows.

I have JAVA_HOME and Path Variables pointing to JDK 17.

I.E. JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-17.0.5.8-hotspot\

AND

%JAVA_HOME% is in path

Understandably, Virtual Environment in Conda is picking up java from jdk-17 at C:\Program Files\Microsoft\.

**_**_

I would like to be able to make at least one of the virtual environments of Conda see version of java from jdk-11.

Please Help ...

__

Note: JDK-11 is installed and is readable (but not while the JAVA_HOME is pointing to jdk-17).

Yes, I can change the JAVA_HOME to point to jdk-11 and make Conda virtual environment point to jdk-11.

However, I'd like to make only the Conda virtual environment point to jdk-11, while still keeping the JAVA_HOME to point to jdk-17, for the rest of the programming environments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep multiple batch files to set the correct JAVA version in your windows computer.

Your java11 batch script might look like

```
   set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11\
   echo Java 11.
```

And java17 batch script should look like

```
   set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-17.0.5.8-hotspot\
   echo Java 11 activated.
```

Now when you want to switch between these two just run the batch script for the version of java you want.

To enable conda to use the jdk11, you can add another conda batch script that invokes the java11 batch script before staring conda.

This is the standard way of managing multiple Java versions in windows.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to enable the switch of Java version only while in a specific Conda env. So, I don't need to change the java version back and forth by running .bat or manually tweaking system env, every time such need arise.  I, perhaps need to tweak activate.bat under the environment. However, I'd like to make sure that attempting to do so don't break the Conda. It'd be nice to find where in Conda a program (.bat, or .exe) refer to Java environment variable. Thank you in advance for further help.

Comment: I am assuming that Conda activate <name_of_venv> fires conda_activate.bat and conda_deactivate.bat is fired just before the environment is deactivated. Can you confirm that?

Comment: I am not sure how conda fires in Windows. But you can write a conda_activate.bat /conda_deactivate.bat etc and add the set JAVA_HOME followed by conda command. That would ensure that the conda uses the proper java.